# Can't change file and folder permissions on rooted device

Tags: file-permissions

I can't change the file and folder permissions on my rooted android 4.4.2 device. I tried doing this from Root Explorer, Total Commander and also from terminal emulator and it didn't worked. Any idea why?

Comment: Permissions of what? Which files or folders? Some filesystems like FAT32 don't support UNIX permissions and therefore you can't change them.

Comment: Yes, i think the problem is because the file system is fat32, though the commands i run from the terminal  `df ` and  `blkid ` didn't get me much info about that.

Comment: Probably refer to [this one](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165059/why-changing-permissions-for-some-systems-files-is-not-allowed/165060#165060) I answered not long ago.

Comment: @user1800997 Which folders are we talking about?

Comment: If you have solved your problem, post the solution as an answer rather than editing your own question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the file system you are working on is mounted as readonly mode.
/system is readonly by default. You need to run the following command to re-mount it as read-write

```
su
mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
```

Another guess is that the file has immutable attribute. Try run this command as root to remove immutable attribute from the file.

```
chattr -i YOUR_FILE
```

Comment: Good answer, which you might want to integrate with some info about the **/storage/emulated/0** mountpoint, since OP didn't specify the culprit folder. In fact, since the abovementioned is masked via **FUSE**, changing ownership and permissions on it isn't allowed, and even the root user has to work on the original folder, which resides in **/data/media/0** in order to edit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fat32 file system of the sdcard.