# Symbolic link permission denied

Tags: sync, 7.0-nougat, camera

I'm trying to create a symbolic link on my Android N phone, so that my photos are accessible from the Pictures folder. I want to be able to sync all my pictures in a single folder using [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net).

My phone isn't rooted, so I booted into a TWRP image using `fastboot boot twrp.img`, where I have root access to the filesystem. I was then able to log in using `adb shell`, create the symlink and change its owner.

```
cd /data/media/0/DCIM
mv Camera Camera.bak
ln -s ../Pictures/Camera Camera
chown -h media_rw:media_rw Camera
```

Unfortunately the camera app fails to open, with an error message saying *No storage found*. Attempting to navigate to the symlink results in a *Permission denied* error.

Is there a way to get this working properly?

Note that in Android `/data/media` is mounted to `/storage/emulated`. The filesystem of `/data` is ext4, which supports symlinks, and the link works correctly from within TWRP.

Comment: `sdcard` usually uses a filesystem that doesn't support permission/symlinking.

Comment: I should have noted that my phone (a Nexus 5) doesn't have a physical SD card. `/sdcard` is just a confusing mount point used by TWRP. I've updated my question to be clearer.

Comment: That's not the point; [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) and the filesystem behind it is usually the culprit. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165059/why-changing-permissions-for-some-systems-files-is-not-allowed/165060#165060) I wrote earlier, and [this](https://twrp.me/faq/datamedia.html) from the TWRP crew.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found this article useful to help in understanding. https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/